# TSLint: Language service execution timeout in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, npm, webstorm, tslint

I'm currently using WebStorm (2017.2.4) on MacOS Sierra and this pop-up shows up once in a while:

[image: Error message]

My colleagues and I have exactly the same TSLint config and code style defined in WebStorm. The problem occurs only on my machine.

I've tried to:

- invalided caches and restart
- reinstall node packages and npm

With no success.

Comment: have you solved it anyhow?

Comment: I've updated WS, and it seems to work in newer version. Still don't know for sure it was that. Currently have Webstorm (2017.2.5).

Comment: Were you using nodenv, by chance?  Or another node environment manager?

Comment: I have used nvm

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this will solve your problem or not.

Enable the plugin in your **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      { "name": "tslint-language-service"}
    ]
  }
}
```

For more detail, please go to this URL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-language-service

Comment: The solution is not relevant to the problem. It is obvious, service is actually running, but not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is due to a big file being linted.
I encountered the same problem while I was running code inspection with WS 2017.3.4 and it showed me the exact file where it came from.
It's a TypeScript file with only 8 lines but one of them is soft wrapped like 300 lines.

I put a `// tslint:disable` on the first line because I anyway didn't need to lint this data file and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Of course you could use `// tslint:disable-next-line` also